# Filter array of objects with another array of objects but just part of string

Tags: javascript

No jQuery, only JS.

```
var array1 = [
  {
    key1: '01',
    key2: 'abc',
    key3: 'def'
  },
  {
    key1: '02',
    key2: 'skip',
    key3: 'skip'
  },
  {
    key1: '03',
    key2: 'ghi',
    key3: 'jkl'
  },
];

var filters = ['ab', 'kl'];

function filter_by_part_of_string(array, filters) {
  return ...
}
```

I would like to get

```
[
  {
    key1: '01',
    key2: 'abc',
    key3: 'def'
  },
  {
    key1: '03',
    key2: 'ghi',
    key3: 'jkl'
  },
];
```

I would like to filter by just part of string in value at any key. I tried search on stackoverflow, but most of answer i found was just filter by string but not a array and part of string.

Comment: Can you please add the code that you tried?

Comment: Will your array objects always contain only 3 key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is to use `some` that will return once an element fulfils criteria:

```
const filter = (terms, arr) => {
    return arr.filter(obj => Object.values(obj).some(val => {
        return terms.some((term) => val.includes(term))
   }))
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function filter_by_part_of_string(array, filters) {
 return array1.filter(obj =>{
  const values =  Object.values(obj).join(' ')
  return filters.filter(f => values.indexOf(f) > -1).length
 })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's presented not in the best way. But it works for now)

```
var array1 = [
  {
    key1: '01',
    key2: 'abc',
    key3: 'def'
  },
  {
    key1: '02',
    key2: 'skip',
    key3: 'skip'
  },
  {
    key1: '03',
    key2: 'ghi',
    key3: 'jkl'
  },
];

var filters = ['ab', 'kl'];

const filterByPart = (array, parts) => {
  let filtered = []  
  array.filter(element => {
    const asArray = Object.values(element)
    asArray.filter(word => parts.filter(part => word.includes(part) && filtered.push(element)))
  })
  return filtered
}

const filtered = filterByPart(array1, filters)
console.log(filtered)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `filter` and check with Regular Expression:

```js
var array1 = [
  {
    key1: '01',
    key2: 'abc',
    key3: 'def'
  },
  {
    key1: '02',
    key2: 'skip',
    key3: 'skip'
  },
  {
    key1: '03',
    key2: 'ghi',
    key3: 'jkl'
  }
];

var filters = ['ab', 'kl'];

const regex = RegExp(filters.join('|'));

const arr = array1.filter(({ key2, key3 }) => regex.test(key2) || regex.test(key3))

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a solution:

```
function filter_by_part_of_string(array, filters) {

  function test(obj) {
    let values = Object.values(obj);

    for (let value of values)
      for (let item of filters) {
        if (value.includes(item)) return true;
      }

    return false;
  }

  return array.filter(test);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope I've been helpful

```
var array1 = [
    {
        key1: '01',
        key2: 'abc',
        key3: 'def'
    },
    {
        key1: '02',
        key2: 'skip',
        key3: 'skip'
    },
    {
        key1: '03',
        key2: 'ghi',
        key3: 'jkl'
    },
];


var filters = ['ab', 'kl'];

var searchBy = "ab";
var array2 = [];
for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; ++i) {
    for (var key of Object.keys(array1[i])) {
        for (var ii = 0; ii < filters.length; ++ii) {
            var str = array1[i][key];
            var n = str.search(filters[ii]);
            if (n > -1) { array2.push(array1[i]) };
        }
    }
}

console.log(array2);
```